# Permanent Login

Tags: php

How can I have permanent login of the people who log in to my site (Even if the browser is turned off) until they log out.

Comment: Why would you keep the session alive? Its good practice to have a session die after some inactivity.

Comment: Are you after the 'stay logged in for x weeks' check box option found on some sites logins?

Comment: Who downed this post, its a valid question asking for what he wanted, ok he does not know the terms but some ppl don't it was a valid question

Answer (score 9):

Use longterm cookies to identify your users.

Example:

```
setcookie('site_user', '<secure_hash>', time()+(3600*24*7)); //expire in a week
```

Notice, this technique involves security problems.

Answer (score 1):

just to expand as you dont want them to logout

erenon's code on your login page changed to support a year

```
setcookie('site_user', '<secure_hash>', time()+(3600*24*7*52)); // now a year
```

this code on every page it will always refresh the cookie if its there to create the never expire now if they log out for a year is the only time they wont stay logged in

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['site_user'])){
    setcookie('site_user', $_COOKIE['site_user'], time()+(3600*24*7*52));
}
```

Comment: Little to add: AFAIk there is appr. 52 week in a year.

Comment: Sorry My Bad lol not quite with it 8:30 in the morning when i posted :p